# Body and html height 100% makes appear scrollbars

Tags: html, css

I know this questionhas already been asked, but the solutions I found don't work. Here is my code :

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

The problem is that a vertical scrollbar appears... Have you got any idea of how I could resolve this ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: the code above won't create the scrollbar, there must be something else.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent scrollbars appearing on any element with the following css:

```
overflow: hidden
```

Comment: Cleaner would be to figure out what's causing the scrollbar because the code in the question shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

There is a 'hackish' way of doing it without using overflow:hidden; if you want to know but I think overflow:hidden itself is already good enough. Check out the code : http://jsfiddle.net/rj3jecc1/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
</div>

body,html{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
body{
    background:#ddd;
}
.container{
    padding-top:1px;
}
.content{
    background:#fff;
    padding:20px;
    margin:20px;
}
```

The problem when you set the body to 100% height is, if you have an immediate child container with margin-top, it will 'push' and exceed the 100% height, causing a scrollbar to appear. That's why I have added another container with 1px (or even 0.1 as long as it's > zero) top padding to prevent that and this solution works across latest version of major browsers.

I don't know why you need the body height to be 100% but I would try not to specify its height unless I know my content will be too 'short' to fit through the height (which isn't a common scenario).